# jQuery Cycle One Pager

Tags: jquery, slider, cycle

I have two jQuery slideshows on one page - something like:

```
jQuery('#one').cycle({
    fit: 1,
    fx: 'custom',
    speed: 700,
    slideExpr: '.slider-one'
});

jQuery('#two').cycle({
    slideExpr: '.slider-two',
    animOut: { opacity: 0 },
    animIn: { opacity: 1 },
    fx: 'custom'
});
```

The problem is that I want only to use one pager for these two. I tried adding to each a class like `.slider-nav` and use:

```
$('.slider-nav').each(function() {
    $(this).cycle({
        prev: '.slider-prev',
        next: '.slider-next',
        timeout: 0
    });
});
```

But it seems only to change the first slider and not the second when I click on either `prev` or `next`. How can I control both ?

Comment: Please post the html as well....

Comment: The html is just basic - bunch of images inside the two containers `#one` and `#two` with the classes shown above.

Comment: Its not really different to this example - http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/pagers.html - the problem is that I want to use only `prev` and `next`

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ankur20us/m9Mgy/10/)

See the demo I used one **prev** and **next** button for it to work

Is this the thing you want?

Comment: Hi thanks for your help. Unfortunately not - look at http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/pagers.html. It's basically the same - however I want to use `next` and `prev`. You can see different containers for each with different animations

Comment: Hi Andy,I updated the answer, for different tranisitions and effects you cant use in single cycle plugin call, in fact I used same prev and next button to do the thing but with different transitions
I used the attribute called transition that will do the trick but I think that is against the norms.